# task tuning in spark and creating checkpoint for task

Tags: apache-spark, sparkcore

while running a spark job, if we have 1000 task's running, out of which 998 are completed and 2 are running in delay. how to identify on which node task are delayed? how can we keep a check point for task to capture delay log?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All that info is available on Spark UI in Stage tab

Comment: Can we create any checkpoint to know that info? Please share any other task tuning techniques.

Comment: What do you mean by checkpoint? What is your goal? Track slow nodes?

Comment: Yes, how can we track the inactive worker nodes, and how can we identify the slow tasks and can we create any checkpoint if it  the time taken for any task is high (ex: if any task exceeds 10 minutes of time for response). And also please share any optimizations in monitoring.

Comment: Monitoring Spark apps is a rather broad topic. I'd start with getting familiar with Spark UI metrics, if you are not already.